# Laravel Command Schedule Not Working Properly

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I'm building a project with Laravel 7.28 on localhost. I need to update a PDF every hour. For the beginning I created a command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Event;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class PDF extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'pdf:update';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'All Country PDFs updated';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        $event = new Event();
        $event->user_id = 1;
        $event->save();

        echo 'done';
    }
}
```

It just insert a record into events table and works fine. Then I edited the Kernel.php under App\Console directory.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\PDF::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('pdf:update')->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__ . '/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Finally, I run `php artisan schedule:run`. I was expecting that the command runs every minute but it just runs once. is this a problem on localhost or did I do something wrong?

Comment: you need something like cron to run the scheduler every minute  ... "When using the scheduler, you only need to add the following Cron entry to your server. "  Introduction - Starting the Scheduler

Comment: @lagbox is this possible on local?

Comment: you would need something like 'cron' on your local system to call the scheduler every minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `php artisan schedule:run` just runs once by its definition:

> The `schedule:run` Artisan command will evaluate all of your scheduled
> tasks and determine if they need to run based on the server's current
> time.

If you want to do it every minute you should use a scheduled process control system like `supervisor` or `crontab` or etc. ([more info here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler))

In case if you are using **laravel 8.x** and running on a development/local server you can use the following command and it will work for you:

```
php artisan schedule:work
```

Comment: I'm afraid ```php artisan schedule:work``` doesn't work.  It's not defined. What else can I do?

Comment: @jigsaw075 sorry just saw you are using Laravel 7, the `schelule:work` works on version 8 only. For you based on your operating system you should use a native scheduled process control system like `cron` or `supervisor` for unix base systems. For windows there are alternative solutions that you can look for like `AlwaysUp`.

Answer (score 2):

On windows localhost

1. First of all set your desired schedule job on the run method inside
   App\Console\Kernel More information on the [Laravel website page here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling)
2. Secondly on the command line run the following
   command

`php artisan schedule:work`

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 7 you can also use below command to run in your local

```
while true; do php artisan schedule:run; sleep 60; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another note for anyone using Laravel Sail, make sure you run it like this:

`./vendor/bin/sail artisan schedule:work`